# Why LYX-2.2.3 closes very slowly?

Tags: lyx

I installed lyx (2.2.3) from ubuntu-18.04 repository. Everything looks fine but I find problem when I try to close the lyx using close button. It closes very slowly normally it takes about 3-4 seconds. How to solve this problem? I would appreciate if anyone suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This was a LyX issue reported [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=mid&q=20171016124934.GC10616%40atrey.karlin.mff.cuni.cz), and fixed for 2.3.1-1 (and later versions) [here](https://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/5a3201a8/lyxgit).

Comment: What is the solution to close fast for lyx-2.2.3?

Comment: There is none because it is a bug in that version of LyX.